# Changing text of a submit button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have coupons available for my app. When a user apply a 100% off coupon I want a button to go from saying "Buy Tickets" to "Get Tickets" using Javascript. This seems easy but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="tickets-actions">
  <%= f.submit "Buy Tickets", class: "button button--primary tickets-actions__item tickets-action" %>
</div>
```

```js
$form.find("[type=submit]").text("Get Tickets")
```

This to me seems like it should work. But I'm not sure what's wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `<input type="submit">` element, the text of the button is in the `value` attribute, so use `val()`, like this:

```
$form.find("[type=submit]").val("Get Tickets")
```